# How do I rename a printer in KDE? (KUbuntu, using 12.04 LTS)

Tags: kubuntu, printing, configuration

the "Printer Configuration" dialogue doesn't offer this.

(There seems to be some kind of [launchpad bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=246704) for it too.)

Answer (score 3):

install: "system-config-printer" e.g:

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-printer
```

run at the command line:

```
user@hostname$ system-config-printer #no sudo was needed
```

It gives you a GUI widget. Right click, and rename away. 
Using LTS 12.04, no restart was needed.

[image: picture of gui applet]